# Hibernate does not store entities in 2nd level Hazelcast cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I'm trying to use Hibernate 5.4.2 second level cache with hazelcast 4.0.1 and hazelcast-hibernate53, when Hazelcast configured in client/server mode, so the JVM working with cache is hazelcast client.

The problem is that entities are NOT added to cache while I do see that hibernate access the cache fine to check if they are in cache in DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad method.

Tried to use both HazelcastCacheRegionFactory and HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory, same issue.

Same worked fine with Hibernate 3.6.9 and older hazelcast, so not sure which part is not working now and which part of hibernate to debug to see why it does not store the entities into the cache.

I'm using HBMs XML so marking every entity if to cache or not like:

```
<class name="MyEntity" dynamic-update="true" table="MyEntity">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
...
</class>
```

Below are hibernate configurations:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
#hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name=hz-main
hibernate.cache.hazelcast.native_client_instance_name=hz-main
hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client=true
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
```

Thanks,
Pavel